# Change hard-coding number along all my code

Tags: xcode, constants

I have to take some long code that I wrote when I didn't know too much and change all the hard-coded numbers to something else .

The numbers are positions on screen, and now I need to make them relative to screen size.

So every `160` on code should turn into  `winSize.width/2`, and `80 = winSize.width/4`.

Is there a simple way to do that in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Find and Replace from the Project Navigator view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press

```
 Command+F
```

when you are ion the file which needs changes.

You will see a bar at the top. On left side there is `Find` written. Click on it. Yoy will get an option `Replace`.
Choose Replace.

In String Matching write `160`.
In below filed write `winSize.width/2`. Click on `Replace All` button.
Do it for value `80` as well.

Comment: PS: You can use the shortcut Cmd + Option + F as well to directly open Replace.

Comment: thanks a lot but this is not good for me, because i have many numbers, such as 137, 563, and i want to change all of them at once to be relative to the screen size . is there another way ?

Comment: I am afraid there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Or `Right Click -> Refactor... -> Rename` also works as well as F&R. It gives you an automatic `diff` like preview of the changes as well, which I think F&R does but you have to click an additional button to get at it.

Comment: True but Refractor only work for C and Objective-C code. If your project is using some C++ code, it won't work unless you temporary change the line "Compile Source As" to Objective-C in the build settings of your project